# Permission denied in omkafka module of rsyslog

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, rsyslog

I am trying to publish messages from rsyslog to kafka on a remote machine using omkafka module.

```
My omkafka action is configured as:
if $HOSTNAME == 'localhost' then {
    action(type="omkafka"
    name="log_kafka"
    broker="192.168.100.50:9092"
    topic="rsyslog_kafka"
    errorfile="/var/log/omkafka/log_kafka_failures.log"
    template="hostipFormat"<br/>
    )
}
```

My kafka instance is running fine and I am able to publish data using kafka-producer.bat file from another windows machine.

But when I start my rsyslog service, I get following error:

> Feb 17 16:42:01 localhost rsyslogd:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0" x-pid="1764" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
>   Feb 17 16:42:05 localhost rsyslogd: omkafka: kafka message 192.168.100.50:9092/bootstrap: Failed to connect to broker at 192.168.100.50:9092: Permission denied [v8.24.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2422 ]
>   Feb 17 16:42:05 localhost rsyslogd: omkafka: kafka message 1/1 brokers are down [v8.24.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2422 ]
>   Feb 17 16:42:05 localhost rsyslogd: omkafka: kafka message 192.168.100.50:9092/bootstrap: Failed to connect to broker at 192.168.100.50:9092: Permission denied [v8.24.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2422 ]
>   Feb 17 16:42:05 localhost rsyslogd: omkafka: kafka message 1/1 brokers are down [v8.24.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2422 ]

I am not sure whether this is related to **omkafka** or **librdkafka**.

Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reason of this issue. It happened because of **SELINUX** in centos. Once I disabled the SELINUX service, the configuration is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Instead of disabling SELinux and thus opening yourself up to a world of hurt. I used `audit2why` which tells you exactly why something is being denied in their avc denials. It is helpful as well in that it can tell you just what you need to do to fix the problem.

Audit2why reads `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and then tells you why something is being denied, and sometimes can tell you what you need to do to fix an issue. In my case it was

`type=AVC msg=audit(1492149030.280:296487): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=2277 comm=72733A6D61696E20513A526567 dest=9092 scontext=system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unreserved_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
    Was caused by:
    The boolean nis_enabled was set incorrectly. 
    Description:
    Allow nis to enabled
    Allow access by executing:
    # setsebool -P nis_enabled 1`

The final commented line there is exactly what needs to be typed to allow this to execute, and it can be done without disabling proper security controls. After `sudo setsebool -P nis_enabled 1` was executed I restarted rsyslog and kafka was able to consume my messages just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely this is related to SELinux, but because disabling SELinux is not best choice I correct problem whit this:

```
sudo semanage port -d -t unreserved_port_t -p tcp 9092
sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 9092
```

And the restart syslogd.